# UI for input form in Android

Tags: forms, android, input

I think, next pattern is common in UI:

- input (or edit) some form
- view this form

It's user-friendly, when this two forms look similar.

In iPhone, they often use standard forms with rounded borders, like that:

[image]

Form looks similar in view and edit mode. And it's good for user...

How to implement such pattern in Android?

Comment: This looks like you're asking for a technical solution ("how to implement..."). That should be asked on StackOverflow

Comment: I'm intresting in concept of UI, not in code. May be some screenshots  of existing apps or sketch with UI for input forms.